# uninitialized constant error, while using JSON and Facebook connect with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm following the tutorial here
http://applicake.com/posts/54-integrating-facebook-connect-with-rails-applications

to set up facebook connect.  It almost worked, except for the last step :-(
I'm getting a JSON error, inspite of installing the JSON plugin.

I did gem install json

How do I fix the problem?

Error in the view:
uninitialized constant SessionsController::JSON

Error on the console:
NameError (uninitialized constant SessionsController::JSON):

Comment: The link that works is http://applicake.com/blog/index.php/2009/07/02/integrating-facebook-connect-with-rails-applications/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to be sure you've got a require for the JSON plugin, correct?

```
require 'json/add/rails'
```

Comment: oops, my bad. I had just require 'json'
aaaah, wasted half an hour.
thank you so much.

Comment: I had a similar issue and installing the json gem then adding require 'json' to my script file solved it.